# compare set1 columns to set2 columns to return names of set1 columns for set2 that match condition

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have a data frame like this:

```
df = read.table(text="ID    S   R1  R2  Sa1 Sa2 Sa4 Sa5 Sa6 Sa7 Sa8 Sa9 Sa10    Sa11
    Chr18_1635988   CC  GG  GG  CC  GG  GG  GG  CC  GG  GG  CC  GG  GG
    Chr18_1636023   AA  TT  TT  AA  TT  TT  TT  AA  AT  TT  AA  TT  TT
    Chr18_1639152   TT  CC  CC  TT  CC  CC  CC  CC  CC  CC  TT  CC  TC
    Chr18_1642235   CC  AA  AA  CC  AA  AA  CA  CC  CA  AA  CC  AA  AA
    Chr18_1643643   --  AA  CC  CC  CC  AA  AA  --  CA  CA  CA  CC  CC
    Chr18_1643660   --  CC  GG  CC  GG  CC  CC  CC  CC  CC  CC  GG  GG
    Chr18_1656020   AA  TT  TT  AA  TT  TT  TT  AA  AA  AT  AA  AA  AT
    Chr18_1657597   CC  TT  TT  CC  TT  TT  TT  CC  CC  CT  CC  TT  TT
    Chr18_1657618   GG  TT  TT  GG  TT  TT  TT  GG  GG  GT  GG  TT  TT", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
 set1 columns 2:4, set2 columns: the names starting with "Sa".
```

I would like to compare set1 with set2, create the "result" row and take the names of set1 for set2 if meet the following conditions:
if the value of any row in set2 matches the value of the same row in "S" column regardless other rows, put the name of "S" column into the location of the corresponding columns in the "result" row; then compare the "R1" or "R2" columns with the unassigned columns in set2.
so the expected result is:

```
final = read.table(text="ID S   R1  R2  Sa1 Sa2 Sa4 Sa5 Sa6 Sa7 Sa8 Sa9 Sa10    Sa11
    Chr18_1635988   CC  GG  GG  CC  GG  GG  GG  CC  GG  GG  CC  GG  GG
    Chr18_1636023   AA  TT  TT  AA  TT  TT  TT  AA  AT  TT  AA  TT  TT
    Chr18_1639152   TT  CC  CC  TT  CC  CC  CC  CC  CC  CC  TT  CC  TC
    Chr18_1642235   CC  AA  AA  CC  AA  AA  CA  CC  CA  AA  CC  AA  AA
    Chr18_1643643   --  AA  CC  CC  CC  AA  AA  --  CA  CA  CA  CC  CC
    Chr18_1643660   --  CC  GG  CC  GG  CC  CC  CC  CC  CC  CC  GG  GG
    Chr18_1656020   AA  TT  TT  AA  TT  TT  TT  AA  AA  AT  AA  AA  AT
    Chr18_1657597   CC  TT  TT  CC  TT  TT  TT  CC  CC  CT  CC  TT  TT
    Chr18_1657618   GG  TT  TT  GG  TT  TT  TT  GG  GG  GT  GG  TT  TT
    result              S   R2  R1  R1  S   S   R1  S   S   R2", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are better served by trying to define the logic in a small helper function

```
f <- \(s,r1,r2,d) {
  d_indx = d %in% c("CC","AA", "GG", "TT")
  case_when(any(d==s)~"S",
    all(d[d_indx] == r1[d_indx])~"R1",
    all(d[d_indx] == r2[d_indx])~"R2"
  )
}
```

Now, simply call that function on each of the `Sa<x>` columns:

```
set2 = names(df)[grepl("^Sa\\d+",names(df))]
result = summarize(df, across(all_of(set2), ~f(S,R1,R2,.x)))
```

Output:

```
  Sa1 Sa2 Sa4 Sa5 Sa6 Sa7 Sa8 Sa9 Sa10 Sa11
1   S  R2  R1  R1   S   S  R1   S    S   R2
```

If you really want this to be appended to the bottom of your original frame, you can do this:

```
bind_rows(df, result %>% mutate(ID="result")
```

Output:

```
              ID    S   R1   R2 Sa1 Sa2 Sa4 Sa5 Sa6 Sa7 Sa8 Sa9 Sa10 Sa11
1  Chr18_1635988   CC   GG   GG  CC  GG  GG  GG  CC  GG  GG  CC   GG   GG
2  Chr18_1636023   AA   TT   TT  AA  TT  TT  TT  AA  AT  TT  AA   TT   TT
3  Chr18_1639152   TT   CC   CC  TT  CC  CC  CC  CC  CC  CC  TT   CC   TC
4  Chr18_1642235   CC   AA   AA  CC  AA  AA  CA  CC  CA  AA  CC   AA   AA
5  Chr18_1643643   --   AA   CC  CC  CC  AA  AA  --  CA  CA  CA   CC   CC
6  Chr18_1643660   --   CC   GG  CC  GG  CC  CC  CC  CC  CC  CC   GG   GG
7  Chr18_1656020   AA   TT   TT  AA  TT  TT  TT  AA  AA  AT  AA   AA   AT
8  Chr18_1657597   CC   TT   TT  CC  TT  TT  TT  CC  CC  CT  CC   TT   TT
9  Chr18_1657618   GG   TT   TT  GG  TT  TT  TT  GG  GG  GT  GG   TT   TT
10        result <NA> <NA> <NA>   S  R2  R1  R1   S   S  R1   S    S   R2
```